# redirection to another page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session, location

I am trying to redirect to users page once use enter login id and password i write code like this

```
<?php

include ('.../database.php');

if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
    // Initialize a session:
    session_start();

    $error = array();//this array will store all error messages


    if (empty($_POST['empno'])) {//if the email supplied is empty
        $error[] = 'You forgot to enter  your Employee No ';
    }
    else {
        $email = $_POST['empno'];
    }
    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';
    } else {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }

    if (empty($error))//if the array is empty , it means no error found
    {
        $query_check_credentials = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (emp_no='$email' AND password='$password')";
        $result_check_credentials = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_check_credentials);

        if(!$result_check_credentials){//If the QUery Failed
            echo 'Query Failed ';
        }

        if (@mysqli_num_rows($result_check_credentials) == 1)//if Query is successfull
        { // A match was made.

            if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
                $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result_check_credentials, MYSQLI_ASSOC);//Assign the result of this query to SESSION Global Variable

                header("Location: http://websiteaddress.com/folder/?page_id=800");

            }

            else
            {
                $msg_error= 'Either Your Account is inactive or Email address /Password is Incorrect';
            }

        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
            foreach ($error as $key => $values) {

                echo '  <li>'.$values.'</li>';
            }
            echo '</ol></div>';

        }


        if(isset($msg_error)){

            echo '<div class="warning">'.$msg_error.' </div>';
        }
        /// var_dump($error);
        mysqli_close($dbc);

    } // End of the main Submit conditional.

?>

Please enter your Employee ID and Password to sign in (both are case-sensitive).

<form action="" method="post" class="registration_form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login Form </legend>
        <p></p>
        <div class="elements">
            <label for="name">Employee No:</label>
            <input type="text" id="e-mail" name="empno" size="25" />
        </div>

        <div class="elements">
            <label for="Password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="Password" name="password" size="25" />
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
            <input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="TRUE" />
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I am not able to go to my user page. every time i enter login button. my page reloaded same url i.e login page.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the condition,

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
```

Instead of,

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
```

Hope this is the problem.